# Cmake outsource packagin or different CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX

Tags: cmake

I am building on  multiple package

I want to set different

```
CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX
```

depending on package type.

For Example :

```
   TGZ: app
   RPM: /usr/local/app
   DEB: /usr/local/app
```

How can I achieve that using cmake ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In place of running 
I am using

```
cpack -D CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/app -G RPM
```